# Passing array of strings through proc

Tags: arrays, scripting, global, maya, mel

This is my code in MEL but I don't know why it's not running:

```
window -width 150;
columnLayout -adjustableColumn true;
    button -label "Button 1" -command "Base";
    button -label "Button 2" -command "Top";
    button -label "Button 3" -command "test";
showWindow;

global string $BaseCurves, $TopCurves;

global proc Base () {
    $BaseCurves=`ls -sl`;
}

global proc Top () {
    $TopCurves=`ls -sl`;
}

global proc test () {
    print $TopCurves[0];
}
```

I don't know why I have this error:

```
"$TopCurves" is an undeclared variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
global string $BaseCurves;

window -width 150;
columnLayout -adjustableColumn true;
    button -label "Button 1" -command "Base";
    button -label "Button 2" -command "Top";
    button -label "Button 3" -command "test";
showWindow;

global proc Base() {
    $BaseCurves=`ls -sl`;
};

global proc Top() {
    $TopCurves=`ls -sl`;
};

global proc test() {
    string $TopCurves[0];
};
```